# Checkboxes selection combination

Tags: javascript, jquery

IF `checkbox1` is selected OR `checkbox1 & checkbox2` show `List1`

IF `checkbox2` is selected show `List2`

ELSE IF both `checkbox1 & checkbox2` are not selected hide both List1 & List2

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ywshcs3/) that doesn't quiet do what I want it to do.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $cBoxes = $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2');
        $cBoxes.change(function(){
          if (($cBoxes.length == $cBoxes.filter(':checked').length)){
            $('#list1').show();
            $('#list2').hide();
          }else{
            $('#list1').hide();
            $('#list2').show();
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: what I have doesn't actually accomplish what I need it to do.

Comment: Is this dynamic? If so, you should be using `.on()` instead of `.change()`. If not, couldn't you just see if `$cBoxes.length == 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cBoxes = $('#data-type-surver-cert, #data-type-assessments');
    $cBoxes.change(function(){            
        if($('#data-type-surver-cert').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('.suvery-cert-list').show();
            $('.assessment-list').hide();
        }
        else if($('#data-type-assessments').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('.suvery-cert-list').hide();
            $('.assessment-list').show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $('.suvery-cert-list').hide();
            $('.assessment-list').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfwngc8j/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the logic is simple enough to use toggle.

```js
$('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').on("change", function() {
    var cb1 = $('#checkbox1')[0].checked;  // or .is(":checked")
    var cb2 = $('#checkbox2')[0].checked;  // or .is(":checked")
    $('#list1').toggle(cb1);
    $('#list2').toggle(!cb1 && cb2);
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/><label for="checkbox1">One</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/><label for="checkbox2">Two</label>

<ul  id="list1">
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul  id="list2">
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/7ywshcs3/3/) looks like what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $cBoxes = $('#data-type-surver-cert, #data-type-assessments');
        $cBoxes.change(function(){
            if ($cBoxes.first().is(":checked")){
            $('.suvery-cert-list').show();
            $('.assessment-list').hide();
          }else if($cBoxes.last().is(":checked")){
            $('.suvery-cert-list').hide();
            $('.assessment-list').show();
          }else
              $('.suvery-cert-list,.assessment-list').hide();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
$('#data-type-surver-cert, #data-type-assessments').change(function () {
    $('.suvery-cert-list, .assessment-list').hide()
    if ($('#data-type-surver-cert').is(':checked') || ($('#data-type-surver-cert').is(':checked') && $('#data-type-assessments').is(':checked'))) $('.suvery-cert-list').show()
    if (!$('#data-type-surver-cert').is(':checked') && $('#data-type-assessments').is(':checked')) $('.assessment-list').show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7ywshcs3/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var $cBoxes = $('#data-type-surver-cert, #data-type-assessments');
    $cBoxes.change(function () {
        var cBoxChecked = $(':checked').length;
        if ((cBoxChecked == 2)) {
            $('.suvery-cert-list').show();
            $('.assessment-list').hide();
        } else {
            $('.suvery-cert-list').hide();
            $('.assessment-list').show();
        }
    });
});
```